# "Error : cannot resolve symbol findViewById"

Tags: android

I'm having a trouble with `findViewById` but I can't find where the problem is.

Here's my FirstFragment class code:

```
public class VehicleInformation extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView text_vehicle_no, text_chassis_no;
    private TextView text_company_name,text_insurance_id;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButton;
    private SpinnerAdapter text_vehicle_class;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vehicle_information, container, false);
        return rootView;

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.insuranceYesNo);

        text_vehicle_no = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_no);
        text_chassis_no = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chassis_no);


        Spinner spinner_vehicle_class = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_class);
        Spinner spinner_vehicle_company = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_company);
        Spinner spinner_vehicle_model = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_model);
        Spinner spinner_vehicle_fuel = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_fuel);
        Spinner spinner_vehicle_color = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_color);
        Spinner spinner_vehicle_types = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_types);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.vehicle_class_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.vehicle_company_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.vehicle_model_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.vehicle_fuel_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter adapter4 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.vehicle_color_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        ArrayAdapter adapter7 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.vehicle_type_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        //specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter7.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        //aaply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner_vehicle_class.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner_vehicle_company.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner_vehicle_model.setAdapter(adapter2);
        spinner_vehicle_fuel.setAdapter(adapter3);
        spinner_vehicle_color.setAdapter(adapter4);
        spinner_vehicle_types.setAdapter(adapter7);


        spinner_vehicle_class.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner_vehicle_company.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner_vehicle_model.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner_vehicle_fuel.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner_vehicle_color.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spinner_vehicle_types.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    }

    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        EditText datePicker=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        datePicker.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus){
                if(hasfocus){
                    DateDialog dialog=new DateDialog(view);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void radiobtn(View view) {
        int radiobtnselect = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(radiobtnselect);
        Toast.makeText(VehicleInformation.this, radioButton.getText(),         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
       String sSelected=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        Toast.makeText(VehicleInformation.this,sSelected,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

}

Also showing error on line

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.vehicle_class_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);"
```

saying wrong 1st argument type

Also showing error on line Toast messsage saying cannot resolve method maketext

Comment: I'm removing the tags for Firebase because it's never referenced in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the `Activity` class, `Fragment` doesn't have a built-in `findViewById()` method. This means you need to use `View.findViewById()`, which you already are doing everywhere except in your `onStart()` method. Here, you can just change this line:

```
EditText datePicker=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
```

to this:

```
EditText datePicker=(EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
```

As for your adapter and toast issues, the problem is that (again, unlike `Activity`), the `Fragment` class is not a subclass of `Context`, so you need to pass a different first argument. Try passing `getContext()` instead of `VehicleInformation.this`.

Comment: thanks and it is also showing error on symbol ft saying " cannot resolve method show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction) " can u also help me to fix this

Comment: Hard to say because I dont' know what `DateDialog` is. It looks like you're trying to show it like a `DialogFragment`, though, in which case you need to make sure you're using the support library for both your dialog fragment and your dialog transaction (or using the main framework for both). Check your imports.

Comment: what is import for dialog transaction? means as dialog fragment has import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment; .................